# Extrating value from json response

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I am getting json response like this

```
"created_at"
        ]=>string(30)"Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014"
```

I want to extract date, time, month seperately. Is it possible via regex?

UPDATE:

i want date, time month each in seperate variable.

Comment: This doesn't seem a valid json response You can check it a [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Decode the json and use the `DateTime` class to manipulate the date / time.

Comment: Please read update question. CAn you please help in scraping the value from output string? i.e. `Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014`

Comment: Can you choose an answer if your happy, it helps with people looking for the answer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing you could do something like

```
$response = json_decode(/* json string */);

$dt new DateTime(response->created_at);

$date = $dt->format('m/d/Y');
$time = $dt->format('H:i:s');

$month = $dt->format('m');
```

This is if your json is valid

Comment: CAn you please help in scraping the value from output string? i.e. `Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014`

Comment: updated, see $hour, $date, $time etc I am just changing the format params :) if you tell me the exact part you want I can edit again.

Comment: Take a look at the above, it now gives you a $date, $time and $month variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DateTime's createFromFormat method. A regex would perform better, but this is a bit easier to read and understand.

```
$created_at = $thing->created_at;
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:m:s O Y', $created_at); // this might be overly verbose

echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2014-03-13
echo $date->format('H:m:s'); // 14:24:13
```

Look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to format the dates.

Comment: if you're decoding json wouldn't' it become an object ? $thing['created_at']; would be $thing->created_at; I could be wrong though.

Comment: CAn you please help in scraping the value from output string? i.e. `Thu Mar 13 14:24:13 +0000 2014` read udated question

Comment: @OliverBS Oh, yeah, it would be an object unless the `assoc` param is true, then it will be an array.